# Preventing multiple errors displaying via toastie

Tags: angular

I implemented `httpinterceptor` in my Angular 8 application and am redirecting to the `systemmaintenance` page when the service is offline. I am also displaying a toastie message via the alert service. At the moment what is happening is that the system emits a number of error messages apart from No network message.

So basically the catch block is executing the return `throwError(error);` multiple times hence you can see multiple messages.

How do I stop after the first toastie message is shown?

One reason that these messages appear is also that once the user tries to navigate to that page, the methods fire to fetch the data from the back end and since the service is offline, the error messages from the respective methods are thrown. Do I need to prevent the user from accessing the component itself and handle it in the router or do I need to manage the toastie messages ones they are thrown. I feel it makes sense for me to handle in the router but not sure how to do it

[image]

This is what `this.alertService.resetStickyMessage()` is in the `httpwebinterceptor`

```
 private stickyMessages = new Subject<AlertMessage>();

 export class AlertMessage {
    constructor(public severity: MessageSeverity, public summary: string, public detail: string, public timeOutSeconds?: number) { }
  }

  resetStickyMessage() {
        this.stickyMessages.next();
    }
```

Httpinterceptor class

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpWebInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(public router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private alertService: AlertService
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('event', event);
                    if(event.status == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                         if (this.router.url == '/offline') {
                             // Website is back online
                             console.log('redirecting to login');
                             this.authService.gotoLoginPage();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.error instanceof Error) {
                    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
                    if(isDevMode()) console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if(isDevMode()) 
                        console.error('Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}');

                    switch(error.status)
                    {
                        case HttpStatusCode.Unknown:
                        {
                            if (this.router.url != '/offline')
                            {
                                this.authService.clearUserData();
                                this.alertService.resetStickyMessage();
                                this.alertService.showMessage("No Network", "The server cannot be reached", MessageSeverity.error);
                                this.router.navigate(['offline']);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return throwError(error);
            }));

    }
}
```

showMessage

```
showMessage(summary: string)
    showMessage(summary: string, detail: string, severity: MessageSeverity, timeOutSeconds?: number)
    showMessage(summaryAndDetails: string[], summaryAndDetailsSeparator: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showMessage(response: HttpResponseBase, ignoreValue_useNull: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showMessage(data: any, separatorOrDetail?: string, severity?: MessageSeverity, timeOutSeconds?: number) {

        if (!severity)
            severity = MessageSeverity.default;

        if (data instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            data = Utilities.getHttpResponseMessage(data);
            separatorOrDetail = Utilities.captionAndMessageSeparator;
        }

        if (data instanceof Array) {
            for (let message of data) {
                let msgObject = Utilities.splitInTwo(message, separatorOrDetail);
                this.showMessageHelper(msgObject.firstPart, msgObject.secondPart, severity, false);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.showMessageHelper(data, separatorOrDetail, severity, false, timeOutSeconds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by redirecting the user from approuting module. So basically I check if the service is offline at that stage in Authuard which takes care of preventing the user from navigating to the page and getting errors

Answer (score 0):

You can add the condition in alertService.showMessage to check if the network is online or offline.

If offline then don't show multiple messages of the calls made in offline

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean as it is still not clear

Comment: I tried this but doesnt work  if (this.router.url != '/offline') {
                    return throwError(error);
                }

Comment: catchError returns an obserable and you need to return something otherwise it throws an error

Comment: I have updated how the showmessage should looks like